# How to add a cooldown in Java?

Tags: java

So I made this, but I only want to allow the user to use it every 10s? How can I do that?
I'm a beginner so bear with me.

```
            if (input == 1) {                    //    Gathering wood     //

            wood += 10;

            System.out.println("You go out into the forest, and find dead brushs and a few sticks lying on the ground. (+10 WOOD)");
            System.out.println("WOOD: " + wood );

            if (wood >= 20) {
                System.out.println("\n\t(!) You have enough wood to build a small hut.\n\n");
            }
            continue;
```

Comment: maybe Thread.sleep

Comment: Take a look at [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: You've not shown enough to indicate how the user "uses" this repeatedly. There's a continue, hinting this is in a loop; but you really should add the loop too for broader context.

Comment: bassically the user input through scanner class a number of the thing he want to do. its in a do while loop to repeat it again <3

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global Date variable which contains the Date/Time where the user has gathered wood the last time.

You can then compare this value to the current Date&Time and check if the time delta is lower than 10 seconds.

Outside the method:

```
public Date lastGathered;
```

Inside your gatherWood() method:

```
if ((LocalDateTime.now().getTime() - lastGathered.getTime()) >= 10000) {
    lastGathered = LocalDateTime.now();
    // Do your stuff
}
```

The value `10000` are milliseconds. So 1 second would be `1000`

Comment: Mhh, technically the same as mine :(

Comment: Using depricated Date when you've got perfect time api from java 8... shame on you

Comment: @RSDinh Sorry, I started answering when no other answer was around. Turns out we had the same idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
```

Comment: That will stop the program from responding, That is not a good answer.

Answer (score -2):

I personally like to use longs for cooldowns.
For your code this example should help you out

```
long actionTime = 0L;
----------------------------
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(input == 1 && currentTime - actionTime >= 10000) {
     actionTime = currentTime;
     //perform extra code here
} else {
     System.out.println("You have to wait: " + (10000 - (currentTime - actionTime)) + " more ms!");
}
```

First you need to initiate a long as 0L since you dont want to wait 10 seconds when you start it

Then you check if the input is 1 and the current time - action time is bigger than 10000

Note: 10000ms = 10 seconds / 1 second = 1000ms

If it is you set the actionTime to the current system time and your problem is solved

Edit: A Swing Timer could probably also solve the issue